# Javascript script doesnt run after other script have been used

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to write some expanding search bar which should expand after clicking upon button and collapse after clicking elsewhere than input field. 
The problem is that everything works just fine, except that after second script sets display: none when I click anywhere around, the first script doesnt launch after I click on button. I tried many variations of code but it doesnt work either, and I dont know what to do, I suppose I just dont understand how JS works here, so if anyone could help it wold be nice :] . 
Below link to codepen with code

```js
        document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
    
      document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.toggle("userInputAnimationToggle");
    
    });
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      let i = document.getElementById("userInputWindow");
      let k = document.getElementById("searchButton");
    
      if(event.target !== i && event.target !== k)
      {
        document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.add("userInputAnimationToggle1");
      }
        
          if(event.target !== i){
            document.getElementById("userInputWindow").value = "";
        }
        });
```

```css
        .searchBoxWrapper{
      position: absolute;
      margin: 40px auto;
      text-align: center;
      left: 50%;
    }
    
    button{
      position:absolute;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin-bottom: 5rem;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: grey;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      border-radius: 100px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      z-index: 2;
    }


    .userInput{
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      padding: 15px;
      border-radius: 40px;
      background-color: grey;
      border: 2px solid orange;
      transform: translateY(50%);
      left: 20px;
      z-index: 1;
      text-align:center;
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    
    .userInput::placeholder{
    font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    .userInputAnimationToggle{
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    }
    .userInputAnimationToggle1{
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
 <div class = "searchBoxWrapper">
 <button class = "openSearchButton" id = "searchButton" type = "button" title = "Open Search window">Search</button>
 <input class = "userInput" value="" type = "text" id = "userInputWindow" placeholder = "     for item"/>
</div>
```

codepen link: https://codepen.io/Mynickname/pen/jepzzX

Comment: I edited you question but attention : `<input/>` instead `<input></input>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the css class `userInputAnimationToggle1`  which was set during hide . i have also edited the `userInputAnimationToggle1` css  value so the search will return to original state

```js
document.getElementById("searchButton").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.remove("userInputAnimationToggle1");
  document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.toggle("userInputAnimationToggle");

});

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  let i = document.getElementById("userInputWindow");
  let k = document.getElementById("searchButton");

  if(event.target !== i && event.target !== k)
  {
   document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.add("userInputAnimationToggle1");
  }

  if(event.target !== i){
    document.getElementById("userInputWindow").value = "";
}
});
```

```css
.searchBoxWrapper{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px auto;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 2;
}


.userInput{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.userInput::placeholder{
font-size: 2rem;
}
.userInputAnimationToggle{
width: 150px;
display: block;
}
.userInputAnimationToggle1{

position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align:center;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class = "searchBoxWrapper">
        <button class = "openSearchButton" id = "searchButton" type = "button" title = "Open Search window">Search</button>
        <input class = "userInput" value="" type = "text" id = "userInputWindow" placeholder = "     for item"></input>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In-stead of adding another class (which is userInputAnimationToggle1) just remove the added class (which is userInputAnimationToggle)

Change the following line

`document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.add("userInputAnimationToggle1");`

to this

`document.getElementById("userInputWindow").classList.remove("userInputAnimationToggle");`

so you won't need the class userInputAnimationToggle1 anymore and can remove it

```
.userInputAnimationToggle1{
    display: none;
}
```